# Como reutilizar modelos en otros proyectos java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, maven, librería

Buen día,
Quisiera saber si existe alguna forma para poder usar modelos de JPA Repository de proyectos ya creados en otros proyectos nuevos. Les explico un poco a que se debe esta duda: Actualmente tenemos una API de login, la cual almacena todas los modelos (Clases) de los usuarios pero debido a algunas necesidades internas se requiere poder usar estos modelos en un proyecto totalmente independiente. Para esto pensé en crear librerías pero por lo que tengo entendido siempre es necesario ingresar manualmente el jar en el proyecto y esto puede generar problemas en cuanto a las versiones, también pensé en poder crear dependencias como las del archivo POM pero no se exactamente si sea posible o como generarlas, necesito de su ayuda para saber como compartir estos modelos entre proyectos de forma eficiente.

Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Bueno, esto es muy dependiente, del entorno de desarrollo a utilizar, y de las necesidades, la cuestion aquí, es si requieres que las clases de ambos proyectos estén syncronizadas, de no ser así, puedes copiar el otro proyecto, completo y modificarlo, o simplemente, copiar los archivos de las clases que necesitas a tu nuevo proyecto, de requerir syncronia, deberas separar las clases en un nuevo proyecto, lanzar un jar del mismo, y syncronizar las librerias a mano, acada vez que las actualices, o puedes preparar un script para que las reemplaze

Answer (score 0):

Lo unico que deberias de hacer es crear un proyecto en donde esten las clases que requieres y compilarlas, una vez compiladas agregarlas al classpath o al conjunto de bibliotecasa traves del IDE y listo, ya son reutilizables. Por ejemplo puedes utilizar Nexus que es un  manejador de repositorios basado en Maven para hacer el manejo de las bibliotecas.